# Убрать швы на склееном изображении

Tags: python, изображения

Подскажите,как с помощью Python убрать швы на изображении? А то сильно видно,что изображение составлено из более мелких.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: что значит "убрать швы"? выровнять границы всего изображения? все равно эффект плитки останется.

Comment: Интересно, а поможет размытие (например, по гауссу) сгладить границы между плитками? :)